# Convert list to n-dimension-array to feed to TFlearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, tflearn

I am developing a CNN to classify images by using TFlearn based on tensorflow, and now I create data sets by using scipy.misc.imread, and I set the image size to 150x150, channels = 3, and now I get a list which contains 4063(the number of my images) (150, 150, 3) array, and now I want to convert it to n-d-array (4063, 150, 150, 3), I don't know how to solve it, please help me. Thank you in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy import misc
from PIL import Image

IMAGE_SIZE = 150
image_path = "dragonfly"

labels = np.zeros((4063, 1))
labels [0:2363] = 1
labels [2364:4062] = 0
test_labels = np.zeros((200, 1))
test_labels [0:99] = 1
test_labels [100:199] = 0

fset = []
fns=[os.path.join(root,fn) for root,dirs,files in os.walk(image_path) for fn in files]
for f in fns:
    fset.append(f)

def create_train_data():
    train_data = []
    fns=[os.path.join(root,fn) for root,dirs,files in os.walk(image_path) for fn in files]
    for f in fns:
        image = misc.imread(f)
        image = misc.imresize(image, (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))
        train_data.append(np.array(image))
    return train_data

train_data = create_train_data()
print (len(train_data))

training_data = train_data[0:2264] + train_data[2364:3963]
train_labels = np.concatenate((labels[0:2264], labels[2364:3963]))
test_data = train_data[2264:2364] + train_data[3963:4063]
```

The train_data is what I got, and it's the list which I want to convert

Comment: I am so sorry I don't know how to post a picture there, I hope you can understand what I said.

Comment: Can u show the part of code you're having trouble with ?

Comment: @Engine, I add it in my question, please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of images (numpy arrays) with shapes (150, 150, 3) then you can simply convert the outer list to a numpy array by the [constructor](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) or calling the [np.asarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) function (which implicitly calls the constructor):

```
np.array([np.ones((150,150,3)), np.ones((150,150,3))]).shape
>>> (2, 150, 150, 3)
```

Edit: in your case add this to `create_train_data` functions return.:

```
return np.array(train_data)
```

---

Alternatively if you want to add multiple numpy arrays into a new numpy array, you can use [numpy.stack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html#numpy.stack) to add them over a new dimension.

```
import numpy as np
img_1 = np.ones((150, 150, 3))
img_2 = np.ones((150, 150, 3))

stacked_img = np.stack((img_1, img_2))
stacked_img.shape
>>> (2, 150, 150, 3)
```

Comment: Actually the length of the list is 4063, when I use np.array(mylist) an error will occured:

Comment: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (150,150,3) into shape (150,150)

Comment: @EnochYang hmm, `return np.array(train_data)` gives you that error?

Comment: File "C:/Users/yangyang/Desktop/untitled0.py", line 56, in create_train_data
    return np.array(train_data)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (150,150,3) into shape (150,150)          @umutto

Comment: @EnochYang I tried with dummy images, I can't reproduce the error. Maybe check all the images are successfully read as RGB images and resized to have the shape `(150,150,3)`. If one of them is black and white, scipy imread may have been reading it without the channels. If it is the problem, you can force RGB mode by using `misc.imread(f, mode='RGB')`

Comment: @EnochYang I was able to reproduce the problem, if the images have different channels it can't convert the list into a numpy array since they all must have the same size. Try explicitly giving 'RGB' argument to `misc.imread` to make sure they are all in same shape. Change your imread line to this `image  = misc.imread(f, mode='RGB')`

Comment: It work, I guess it's problem of my image data, really thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [np.asarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) on the list.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = []
>>> for i in range(4063):
...     l.append(np.zeros((150,150,3)))
...
>>> type(l)
<type 'list'>
>>> a = np.asarray(l)
>>> type(a)
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> a.shape
(4063, 150, 150, 3)
```

Comment: I tried it, but the result is the same @ShaunBarney

Comment: File "C:/Users/yangyang/Desktop/untitled0.py", line 91, in <module>
    X = np.asarray(training_data)

  File "E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 531, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (150,150,3) into shape (150,150)